# Serialising a Java Map with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I am using Jackson library for serialising JSON,

having Serialising a Java Map, for ex, `map<String,String>` has

```
{<color, green>,<color, blue>}
```

I want this to be serialised as

```
"colormap":[{"key": "color":, "value":"green"}, {"key": "color:, "value":"blue"}]
```

but its always serialising as

```
"colormap":[{"color":"green"}, {"color:"blue"}]
```

Comment: A `Map` cannot have duplicate keys. What is the real data you have? Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Looks like a `List<Map<String,String>>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your output JSON is an array, not a map- Without looking at your code it's hard to tell what the underlying data structure is,but to do what you're looking for you might consider a class such as:

```
class Thing {
  private String key ;
  private String value ;
  /// add accessors as needed
}
```

and then declare your colormap as `List<Thing>`. This should seralize your data per your expectation.